# VBA Find function can't pull string from outside the loop it's in

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, find

I'm writing code to convert temperature data in multiple workbooks within the same folder--data looks like this, except as a worksheet:

```
Site Id Date    TMAX.D-1 (degC)     TMIN.D-1 (degC)     WSPDV.D-1 (mph)     RHENC.D-1 (pct)     LRADT.D-1 (lang) 
2031    5/5/2019    21.6    5   6.1 64  382.83
2031    5/6/2019    25.9    13  8.8 68  348.68
2031    5/7/2019    17.3    9.4 9   70  258.88
```

The user selects if the temperature needs converting (If TC = 1 pulls the yes/no answer to a question message box), then gives me the column header to be saved as a string:

```
    If TC = 1 Then
        Dim RawTemp_max As String
        Dim RawTemp_min As String
        Dim TempUnits As String
        RawTemp_max = Application.InputBox("Type or copy in the column label of your maximum temperature data", "Data Select", Type:=2)
        RawTemp_min = Application.InputBox("Type or copy in the column label of your minimum temperature data", "Data Select", Type:=2)
        TempUnits = Application.InputBox("Type the UNITS your temperature data is in, exactly as seen here: F, K", "Units", Type:=2)
```

So far, so good--the column headers are consistent across all workbooks, so this shouldn't cause issues. Then I have a loop to open each workbook in turn, find the temperature columns, add a new column and perform calculations (myFile is defined at the beginning of the sub and not included here, it's the file to open):

```
'Loop through each Excel file in folder
  Do While myFile <> ""

        Workbooks.Open FileName:=(myPath & myFile)
        Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Dim bname As String * 5
        bname = wb.name
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
        DoEvents

    'Setup for all
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Temperature
        If TC = 1 Then
           Dim MaxTemp As Range
           Dim MinTemp As Range
           Dim xT As Range
           Dim nT As Range
           Dim NewMax As Range
           Dim NewMin As Range
           With ws.UsedRange
                Set xT = .Find(RawTemp_max, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not xT Is Nothing Then
                    Set MaxTemp = Range(Cells(1, xT.Column), Cells(LastRow, xT.Column))
                    MaxTemp.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 2).Insert
                    Set NewMax = Range(Cells(2, MaxTemp.Column + 1), Cells(LastRow, MaxTemp.Column + 1))
                End If
           End With
        End If
   Loop
```

It seems to be unable to find the temperature column specified by RawTemp in the <.Find(RawTemp, LookIn:=xlValues)> function, as it keeps giving me an "Error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set" on the next line when I try to set the range. I've tried xT.select to troubleshoot and it's not finding the cell at all.

I tried it without the With block (coded as ws.Find(RawTemp, LookIn:=xlValues) and got the same error. Can you not pass a string into a loop? There shouldn't be a mismatch between the string and the column header, I've checked.

Thanks!

Comment: `Range.Find` returns `Nothing` if it doesn't find what it's looking for; you can't do `With Nothing`, so `With Range.Find(...)` is a recipe for error 91. Watch out for unqualified `Range` and `Cells` calls, they're implicitly referring to whatever the `ActiveSheet` is. Also consider `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)` instead of discarding the returned object and relying on side-effects for setting `wb` to the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thanks. The question really is "why is it returning nothing?" when the string it's trying to find is copied directly from the worksheet. I've tried it without the 'with' function and had the same error, and both copied in the column header and typed it.